# MS SQL Server select unique rows based on column value

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have an SQL select query that joins different tables. The result is something like the first table below

```
p_id | colAprimaryEQsecondary | p_cat | colA | colB | colC  
-----|------------------------|-------|------|------|------
001  |           1            |   1   |  x   | boo1 | flo1    
001  |           1            |   2   |  x   | boo1 | flo1    
002  |           0            |   1   |  a   | boo2 | flo2    
002  |           0            |   2   |  b   | boo2 | flo2    
003  |           1            |   1   |  z   | boo3 | flo3    
003  |           1            |   2   |  z   | boo3 | flo3
```

`p_id` represents the foreign key column of the database. Every cell value is the same within each row with corresponding `p_id`s (`p_cat` is supposed to be different), except sometimes column `colA` has 2 different values. Column `colAprimaryEQsecondary` contains a `0` or `1`. `1` meaning the `colA`-value is the same in rows with corresponding `p_id`.

I want to get a result like this:

```
p_id | colAprimaryEQsecondary | p_cat | colA | colB | colC  
-----|------------------------|-------|------|------|------
001  |           1            |   2   |  x   | boo1 | flo1     
002  |           0            |   1   |  a   | boo2 | flo2    
002  |           0            |   2   |  b   | boo2 | flo2    
003  |           1            |   2   |  z   | boo3 | flo3
```

So I want to create an SQL query that looks at the value of `colAprimaryEQsecondary`. If the value equals `0` I want to get both rows, if the value equals `1` I only want to get the row with `p_cat` equals 2.

I tried doing this with different methods, `group by`, `select distinct`, `select distinct on`, `case`, but I couldn't get the right select query. (Unfortunately I have deleted the select statements I tried).

How would I solve this?

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with simple logic in the `WHERE` clause:

```
with q as (
      <your query here>
     )
select
from  q
where (colAprimaryEQsecondary = 0) or
      (colAprimaryEQsecondary = 1 and p_cat = 2)
```

Comment: Great! Works fine.
A question though, let's say the ones creating the original tables weren't careful enough with filling `colAprimaryEQsecondary` the right way. Is there also a way inside the select query where I can check `colA` for differences, and if there is, then select those as well? Should I do this with 2 SQL queries inside a third `where` clause?

Answer (score 1):

```
DECLARE @DataSource TABLE
(
    [p_id] CHAR(3)
   ,[colAprimaryEQsecondary] TINYINT
   ,[p_cat] TINYINT
   ,[colA] CHAR(1)
   ,[colB] VARCHAR(8)
   ,[colC] VARCHAR(8)
);

INSERT INTO @DataSource ([p_id], [colAprimaryEQsecondary], [p_cat], [colA], [colB], [colC])
VALUES ('001', '1', '1', 'x', 'boo1', 'flo1')
      ,('001', '1', '2', 'x', 'boo1', 'flo1')
      ,('002', '0', '1', 'a', 'boo2', 'flo2')
      ,('002', '0', '2', 'b', 'boo2', 'flo2')
      ,('003', '1', '1', 'z', 'boo3', 'flo3')
      ,('003', '1', '2', 'z', 'boo3', 'flo3');

SELECT * 
FROM @DataSource
WHERE [colAprimaryEQsecondary] = 0
UNION ALL
SELECT [p_id], [colAprimaryEQsecondary], MAX([p_cat]), [colA], [colB], [colC]
FROM @DataSource
WHERE [colAprimaryEQsecondary] = 1
GROUP BY [p_id], [colAprimaryEQsecondary], [colA], [colB], [colC];
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try a union of two different query one having a where clause with colAprimaryEQsecondary =0 and the other with colAprimaryEQsecondary=1 and 
for colAprimaryEQsecondary=1 do a  count on colAprimaryEQsecondary.